# Differencce between interface and API

Tags: api, interface

could you please explain the difference between interface and API?

I was looking for this information here and using google but I only find a special information for Oracle.

What I'm looking for is the general difference.

Much appreciated!

Update: 
thank you all for the answers. My question was kept deliberately general because I 
1) do not have the detailed information about the used programming languages (question based on a short information about one vendor's implementation in my project);
2) I wanted to understand the general high-level difference between the both terms.

Comment: Application programming interface (API). So, in some sense, that is an interface. Perhaps you can clarify what programming language you are asking about, and in what context you've mixed those words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further context, your question is a bit broad; but lets try; by looking up the definition of API on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface):

*In computer programming, an application programming interface (API) is a set of subroutine definitions, protocols, and tools for building software and applications.*

Then: API stands for *application programming **interface***; indicating that well, an API contains **all elements** (plural!) required to create an application which wants to interact with the component behind that API.

Whereas an interface in its stricter sense typically denotes a "single specific entity"; like the *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)* interface in java describes an ordered collection (without providing details about specific implementation).

But of course, there are certain commonalities - both terms are about the description of the "boundary" of a "system".  Long story short: there is simply no sharp, precise separation between those two concepts. Thus, when using those words within a group of people, you might want to first "step back" and discuss terminology - to ensure that all people involved have the same understanding of such terms. Or as [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) puts it: you want to create a **Ubiquitous Language** in which such terms have a clear, well defined meaning.

Finally: it is also worth mentioning that the term *interface* has different meanings when using different programming languages. In Java, an interface is really a **concept** embodied within the language core; where as in C++, an "interface" would probably be seen as the content of a single header file; leading to subtle but important "flavors" of "interface" for those two languages.

Edit:

1. Both, interface and API should not expose (too much?!) of the internals to the outside world.
2. Generally speaking, an API outlines a "component" (a complete "application" for example); whereas an interface might outline a "smaller" entity".
3. For your other refinement, about one company providing the API, and another the interface - I cant say anything. Because; as others have explained too: the definitions for those terms are really to unclear/fuzzy. We would need to know much more about the application and its requirements to even comment on your statement here.

Comment: Thank you, GhostCat! So correct me please if I'm wrong: do you mean, an API comprises more detailes about the "rules of the boundary" (but also like an interface not the implementation itself)?

Comment: And some more details about the context. One company is going to work on API and another one on interface for the same process. The company that should work on the interface delivers the basic information. The company that should work on API uses this information to be able to provide users with some functionality based on the information received via API.

Comment: I made some updates; but I am not sure if anything "new" is in there. I fear that "talking on such general level" (especially given your latest example); it is simply not possible to come back with anything more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much, GhostCat!

Answer (score 2):

The question "what is the difference between X and Y" is only meaningful when X and Y have single meanings and strict definitions.  But "interface" and "API" do not have either single meanings nor strict definitions, so one cannot tell what is the difference between them.

For the most part, there is no difference, but there exist certain contexts where one would be suitable to use, while the other would be less suitable, or even unsuitable.

So, for example, a class implements an interface, never an API.  On the other hand, an entire software system is more likely to be said to expose APIs rather than interfaces, though to say interfaces in this case would not be wrong either.

I wish there was some easy distinction, like "interfaces are small-scale, APIs are large-scale", or "interfaces are more specific, APIs are more nebulous", but there is no such distinction.

Comment: I was tempted to give you a +1 for this; but then I saw your really harsh comment to the now-deleted answer by Usmann. I think that analogies can be helpful in almost any setting; the **scientific** part when using analogies is to have a clear understanding how "good" the analogy matches; and which parts of that "projection onto some other canvas" need to be handled with care.

Comment: @GhostCat well, then, I guess we disagree.  But I assure you that my comment and downvote was not based on my dislike of using analogies to make a technical point, because I realize that this may just be a personal preference of mine.  I read the analogies and I found that they were very poor, completely failing to shed any light to the nature of APIs and interfaces, containing elements that are actually unsuitable to describe these entities, AND failing to show the difference between the two.  In other words, complete fail on all accounts.  But anyway, thanks for your input.